# Accessing Ubuntu Partition from Windows 7

Tags: partitioning

My question is this: Is it possible to access my Ubuntu Partition from Windows? I can access Windows with no problem from Ubuntu (12.04), yet when I try from Windows, all I can see is the boot directory.

I've looked up this problem before, yet all I usually find is the opposite problem.

My specs are:

AMD A8-4500M with Radeon HD Graphics 1.90GHz

6 GB RAM

64-Bit OS

750 GB HDD, split directly down the middle, i.e, half for Windows 7 and half for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 

Toshiba Satellite L855D PSKE8C-00P001

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: windows can't handle the ext4 filesystem by default. So your best bet would be googling "windows 7 with ext4" and then go from there. Personally I've never tried it and was always very comfortable in knowing that there is no way in hell windows could access my ubuntu drive ;)

Answer (score 4):

It is possible but not without third party software.

There are a handful of them but I think this one will do the trick [Ext2Explore](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/)

[Here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/06/access-ubuntu-from-windows-7) is more detail.

Basically you are going to install the program like any other program and then browse your Ubuntu Partition.

Although the best scenario is this:

Create 3 equal partitions, Once for your windows install, one for your data (must be NTFS), and then your Linux(Ubuntu) partition. If you do this, you will be able to save/access your documents to the data partition regardless of what OS you are currently booted into.

Answer (score 3):

The crucial point, altought the implementations are absolutely free (I think they are released under a GPL3), is that Microsoft doesn't want you to use file systems apart from FAT and NTFS.

However you can access ext2-3 file systems using some workaround not officially supported, as this: http://www.fs-driver.org/

Please be **careful** in what you are doing and read **carefully** all the instructions and warnings on that site **before** doing anything.

Comment: Is fs-driver able to access files more efficiently than ext2fs?

Comment: @AndersonGreen I don't know, I don't use Windows any more and for sure, I would not use it for access my Ubuntu files.